# Managed and unmanaged code error C3699

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I am working on a game which uses C# and C++. Classes for models are written in C# and levels structure is stored in XML files. When I want read it in C++ and want to build project I have this strange error and I don't where to find some bugs.

```
Error   1   error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type 'Cadet::XMLReader::Models::Obstacle' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0 527 1   Cadet.Game
```

These kind of errors are in `xmemory0` and `list` files? what they are? and it happend only for Obstacle class, the rest are fine.

Here it is part of the code

```
    void SetupObstacles(std::list<Cadet::Game::Entities::Obstacle>  &obstacles)
    {
     int size = CurrentLevel->Obstacles->Length;
     Cadet::XMLReader::Models::Obstacle^ currentObstacle;
  }
```

Comment: which part because these errors shows in xmemory0 and list files not in some of files of the project

Comment: try building by commenting xmemory0 so that we could know the source of the problem

Comment: @nsconnector how to do that?

Comment: Have u checked this link?It might be helpful to you
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/440b26de-48fe-4103-8d81-2ca897cf233d

Comment: does it build if you comment the following line?
Cadet::XMLReader::Models::Obstacle^ currentObstacle;

Comment: but I don't know in which part of my code I have to look for errors? VS2012 says that in xmemory0 and list files

Comment: no it doesn't compile, the same errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25890/discussion-between-nsconnector-and-tomasz-kowalczyk)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Cadet::Game::Entities::Obstacle` is a managed class (since you've declared `currentObstacle` as a reference with `^`).  If that's the case, you can't directly store managed objects in STL containers like `std::list<>`.

It's hard to say what to do next w/o more context, but one possible fix would be to change your `SetupObstacles` method:

```
void SetupObstacles(System::Collections::Generic::List<Cadet::Game::Entities::Obstacle>^ obstacles)
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a pointer to an `Obstacle` somewhere?

The [help on this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ctbshy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that some types (such as trivial properties) cannot have a reference type--you can't have a pointer to it.  Try using `^` instead.